# How to get instance in Kotlin with Context.getSystemService(Class)

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack

In Google Android Kotlin documentation, 
Every now and then there is a below line present in android documentation that:
**Instances of this class must be obtained using Context.getSystemService(Class)**

For example:

> Instances of this class must be obtained using Context.getSystemService(Class) with the argument AppOpsManager.class or Context.getSystemService(String) with the argument Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE.

Can someone please clarify what this is and how do I create a instance for class `AppOpsManager`.

Usually we can create instance like:
`val use = AppOpsManager()`

Please help and explain the above `Context.getSystemService()`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager) documentation:

> **AppOpsManager**
>
> API for interacting with "application operation" tracking.
>
> This API is not generally intended for third party application
>   developers; most features are only available to system applications.
>
> Instances of this class must be obtained using
>   `Context.getSystemService(Class)` with the argument
>   `AppOpsManager.class` or `Context.getSystemService(String)` with the
>   argument `Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE`.

To create an instance of this class you must use `getSystemService` from a context instance.

```
val appOpsManager: AppOpsManager? = getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager?
```

If your `minSdkVersion` is 23 then you can use this code instead.

```
val appOpsManager: AppOpsManager? = getSystemService(AppOpsManager::class.java)
```

Comment: While the docs say that `getSystemService (Class<T> serviceClass)` has been added in API level 23, it actually works in older Android versions as long as your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher.

Comment: I cannot confirm what Cristian writes, when using the class based variant with minSdkVersion < 23, Android Studio shows an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
context.getSystemService(AppOpsManager::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val aom = getSystemService(context, AppOpsManager::class.java)
```